# ModalPopupExtender controls become visible when debug is set to false

Tags: asp.net, debugging, modalpopupextender

I have deployed an ASP.NET Web Forms application to an IIS7 web server.  It works perfectly as long as the setting in the Compilation section of *Web.config* is `debug=true`.  As soon as I change it to `debug=false`, which I understand is what I'm supposed to do when the application is live, pages don't render correctly.

Specifically, a page which has a Panel that is associated with a ModalPopupExtender loads with the controls that are inside the Panel displayed right from the off.  It's not that the Panel is displayed when it shouldn't be, it's that the controls from inside the panel are rendered as if they're not inside the Panel, leading to controls scattered randomly across the page.

As soon as I set `debug=true` again, the problem goes away.

EDIT: After further playing around, I've discovered that even if `debug=true` is set in *web.config*, if I set the `ScriptMode` property of the *ToolkitScriptManager* on my page to `Release`, that too causes the same incorrect behaviour of my ModalPopupExtender enabled Panel.  So, for things to work properly I have to have `debug=true` in *web.config* and `ScriptMode=Debug` in a page's *ToolkitScriptManager*.  What's going on?  Don't Microsoft want me to release my application?

ADDITIONAL INFO:
My Web.config file shows that I'm targeting version 4.5 of the .NET Framework, and whilst looking at the Application Pool in IIS seems to show that my applications on the web server are all using version 4, I'm not especially proficient with IIS, so I've posted a screenshot below.  And would this cause the problem I'm experiencing anyway?

[image]

Comment: which version of ajaxcontroltoolkit you're using?

Comment: I'm using v4.1.7.1005.

Comment: isn't this an outdated release?

Comment: It seems that there is a slightly newer release available, I'll try upgrading.

Comment: Upgraded to the latest version of AjaxControlToolkit - problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a conflict between your Application Pool version and your config file. Maybe you are using v4.0 App Pool, and your web.config is configured for v2.0 or vice versa.

Please check your versions and leave a comment with this answer and let's check. :)

**--EDIT--**

You may have 3 options:

1. [Downgrade](http://jacstech.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/downgrading-an-mvc4-project-from-net-4-5-to-4-0/) your web.config from 4.5 to 4.0.
2. Upgrade [.NET framework](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/download/details.aspx?id=30653) installed in your machine.
3. Set the panel's style display to none:

   < asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" style="display: none;">

Comment: It seems that web.config is targeting v4.5 and the Application Pool v4, but I'm not that au fait with IIS so I've edited my question and included a screenshot of the Application Pool screen.  Would a difference of versions between 4 and 4.5 cause a problem anyway?  The ModalPopupExtender is hardly a new control!

Comment: Your answer is wonderfully clear and the links are great - thank you!  Unfortunately, I have successfully retargeted my application to v4.0 of the .NET Framework, to match the server, but the problem persists with the ModalPopupExtender's panel controls still visible right from page load.

Comment: You can try the 3rd option that I've added in my answer. :)

Comment: Just tried that (even though it's only addressing the symptom not the cause), but with that property set, whilst the controls don't appear when the page loads, the panel also doesn't appear when I click on the control that's supposed to make it do so!

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't a direct solution to your problem that you are asking about, you can hide the panel on page load (not post back) for any pages that have this issue.  I have seen this be used as a workaround in the past for the ModalPopupExtender showing controls on page load in different scenarios.  This should prevent the controls from being rendered on the page inappropriately but still work for when it needs to pop up.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        pnl.Visible = false;
}
```

I have also found that getting the latest version of .NET framework on your machine that hosts the website fixes a lot of issues like this.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I expect this would work, but I would rather get to the cause of the problem rather than just mask the symptom.  I will see if I can update the server's .NET version, though.

Comment: As an update, I gave this a try in the end, and whilst the controls in the panel didn't show up on page load, clicking the button to show the panel doesn't do anything. It's the same as setting `display: none` on the panel (which I've also tried) - it prevents the panel from ever being visible.

Comment: Did you add code that makes the panel visible again explicitly in your button click that shows the modal?

Comment: Yes, I called ModalPopupExtender.Show()